# Failed to connect to MySQL: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, connection

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied in /storage/ssd2/659/6067659/public_html/getCourse.php on line 4
>   Failed to connect to MySQL: Permission denied
>   Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /storage/ssd2/659/6067659/public_html/getCourse.php on line 16
>   Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /storage/ssd2/659/6067659/public_html/getCourse.php on line 36

I’m getting this error lately, my database connection was working before and Idk why it’s not now

EDIT: turns out the server was down..

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
    Type="MYSQL"
    HTTP="true"
    $hostnameGS = "localhost";
    $databaseGS = "gene_structure";
    $usernameGS = "kwatanabe";
    $passwordGS = "password";
    $connGS = mysqli_connect($hostnameGS, $usernameGS, $passwordGS,$databaseGS) or 
    trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```